# fittedbox with maximum two lines in flutter

Tags: flutter, fitted-box

```
Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 60),
        child: Text(
          //  subCategoryName,
          "This is a very Long Text takes more space",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          maxLines: 2,
          overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .headline3
              .copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 32),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

[Look this Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy9jo.png)

I need this line to be a maximum of two lines and shrink the size like a FittedBox (with BoxFit.fitWidth) if the text gets even longer

When I used the FittedBox it looking [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHgfb.png). But I need to take it up to 2 lines if needed.. Any solution is appreciated

Comment: Maybe [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) can help you

Answer (score 8):

Got it working by the reply of **Sam Chan**.
I used the [AutoSizeText](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) Package